# mysql multiple unique values per primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores multiple phone numbers. While the same number can exist in the table I want to ensure that a user can't have the same number twice.

```
**Valid**

id0001 : 5555550000
id0001 : 5555550001
id0002 : 5555550000

**Invalid**

id0001 : 5555550000
id0001 : 5555550000
id0002 : 5555550001
```

Not sure the best approach.  Should I make a function and apply it as a constraint?

Should I change the structure of the table?

```
CREATE TABLE `callback` (
    `f_unti_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `phone_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `callback` ADD CONSTRAINT `callback_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`f_unti_id`) REFERENCES `unit`(`unit_id`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a composite (a.k.a. compound or multi-column) `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE callback
(
    f_unti_id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,

    -- Compound PK
    PRIMARY KEY(f_unti_id, phone_number)
);
```

(Actually, a `UNIQUE` constraint on multiple columns would suffice. Check [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)).

Try it a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9882a/1/0

Comment: This answer is correct, but I don't see any point in having one UNIQUE key that isn't a primary key.  Every table should have a primary key, especially if you're using InnoDB for the engine.  On InnoDB, if you don't specify a primary key, a hidden clustered index based on the row ID is created.  The row ID is not consistent across servers (as in a replication setup) and can not be accessed by the user or used to apply row-formatted replication events.  Short version is -- there's no downside and some advantage to making the only unique key the primary key.

Comment: In this specific case, I agree that making the UNIQUE key a PRIMARY KEY (when you already have both parts of the key to be NOT NULL) is clearly an advantage; and makes sense from a *semantic* (not just purely technical) perspective. **In general** you need a UNIQUE constraint to guarantee *unicity*, which is what the OP is asking for. You don't *necessarily* need it to be a primary key.

Comment: It is bad not to have a `PRIMARY KEY` on an InnoDB table.  In most situations, it is wasteful to have both a `PRIMARY KEY` and a `UNIQUE KEY`; almost always you should just have the PK specify the uniqueness constraint you desire.

Comment: thanks joanolo,  I went with the multiple constraints approach and it worked like a charm.   regards,